# FileNotFoundException while accessing a file from JSP

Tags: eclipse, jsp, filenotfoundexception

I have a Java program which uses a lot of text files. The program runs perfectly fine when run as a standalone Java application. But it won't work when I call the same method from a JSP page. It says its unable to find the text files. Gives a `FileNotFoundException` for each text file in the project.

Any help would be much appreciated. I am using SpringSource Tool Suite 2.8 for Mac. TC server.

This is the error:

The same for 1.txt to 99.txt:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: 100.txt (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your JSP page is not running from the same location as your program did. If you are running your JSP inside Tomcat or something similar then it will be running from the server's webapps (or similar) folder. You should probably change the path specified in the JSP to fully qualify the location of the text file.

For example, don't put this:

```
\testfiles\hello.txt
```

put this

```
c:\bob\testfiles\hello.txt
```

Comment: As much as I agree with given error reason, I would opt for using [ServletContext#getResource()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) instead of passing an absolute path. Absolute paths makes assumptions about available resources *outside of the container* which might be problematic in the future.

Comment: OH!! I am using the path of text files in the Java method. I am only Calling this Java method in the jsp..... SO, technically, if the program runs fine and the JSP can make a successful call to the program then Should I not have the results!!!?? Please let me know...thanx for the quick response..... and by the way... All the text files, java files, and JSP and HTML pages are in one Project directory.....  THANKS... ARYA.